# Teamcity git push error - could not read username while using maven release perform

Tags: git, maven, github, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm new to Teamcity, I've configured the release build for one of the maven projects on **teamcity (8.1.5)** with vcs root set to **GIT**.

for VCS root I've configured git repo url and using password authentication during checkout. It checks out Git repo successfully but it fails to execute mvn release:prepare on it and throws error

```
The git-push command failed.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

I know this error means no appropriate credentials helper configured on teamcity but why teamcity does not pick up the username/pwd configured in auth section by default.

Even I tried passing credentials using mvn arguments and pom has following scm settings

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/abc/sp.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/abc/sp.git</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:git:https://github.com/abc/sp.git</url> </scm>
```

[image: vcs root auth setting]
[image: maven configuration]

how should I make it work for git push ?  I could not find this in TC documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with all the above settings, I had to update my pom to add the latest of version of maven release plugin and it worked fine

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>                
</plugin>
```